# Multi-thread Linux tool commands?

Tags: python, multithreading, command-line

I want to create a script that will run two Linux based tools from the shell at the same time and based on write their outputs into a single results file?

I am pretty clueless in all honesty having done some research into things such as `os.fork` and such and was really just looking for some guidance.

I am currently using `subprocess.call([command here])` to run one command and output that into a file but I was just wondering how I could run two tools simultaneously such as.

```
subprocess.call([command 1 >> results.txt])
subprocess.call([command 2 >> results.txt])
```

Both of these happening at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you'll want to call `Popen` rather than `call` if you want to run these simultaneously as `call` blocks until the process finishes. Also you can use the stdout parameter to pipe the output to a file like object.

```
with open("results.txt", "w") as results:
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(["command1"], stdout=results)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(["command2"], stdout=results)
    p1.wait()
    p2.wait()
```